# I want to fill a matrix structure with 0s

Tags: c

I have this method where I pass a matrix structure and the size of it, then i have an element that i will use to fill that matrix  with.
I keep getting Segmentation Fault (core dumped) and I'm not sure why.

```
void initMatRes(matrix *matrixR, int nRow, int nCol) {
 int i,j;
 matrixR->row=nRow;
 matrixR->column=nCol;
 matrixR->used = 0;
 matrixR->elements = malloc(nRow *nCol * sizeof(float));

 element element0;
 element0.value = (float) 0;

 for(i=0;i< nRow;i++){
    for(j=0;j< nCol;j++){
        element0.row=i+1;
        element0.column=j+1;
        insertArray(matrixR,element0);
    }
  }
}
typedef struct{
 int row;
 int column;
 float value;
}element;

typedef struct {
 int row;
 int column;
 int nonzero;
 element* elements;
 size_t used;
 size_t size;
}matrix;

 void insertArray(matrix *matrix1, element nonzeroEle) {
  if (matrix1->used == matrix1->size) {
    matrix1->size *= 2;
    matrix1->elements = realloc(matrix1->elements, matrix1->size * sizeof(int));
  }
  matrix1->elements[matrix1->used++] = nonzeroEle;
 }
```

Insert array store a pointer to an element into elements, so i have all my elements of the matrix there.

Comment: What is `insertArray`? What are `matrix` and `element`? Does the arguments have proper values? Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Additional code should be added to your question by [edit]ing that, not to comments.

Comment: Why are you adding 1?

Comment: And if adding 1 is correct, why not do that in the loop variables: `for (i = 1; i <= nRow; i++)`

Comment: Look at the declaration of `elements`.  It's an `element *`.  Now look at the `malloc` call.  It's using `sizeof(float)`.  Change it to `sizeof(element)`.  You aren't allocating enough memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
matrixR->elements = malloc(nRow *nCol * sizeof(float));
```

This doesn't allocate enough space, as you are only allocating space for floats, while you point to a struct containing addítional members.

```
 matrixR->elements = malloc(nRow *nCol * sizeof(*matrixR->elements));
```

Also here

```
matrix1->elements = realloc(matrix1->elements, matrix1->size * sizeof(*matrixR->elements));
```

Comment: `matrix1->elements = realloc(matrix1->elements, matrix1->size * sizeof(int));` is also wrong.

Comment: Do not use `sizeof(type)` for this. Use `matrixR->elements = malloc(nRow * nCol * sizeof *matrixR->elements);`. Then the mistake of using the wrong type cannot occur.

Comment: The float member is already initialized at `element0.value = (float) 0;`.